# How to add login with facebook without identity in MVC

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an existing MVC application and log in and register are implemented without identity using the simple membership, I've searched in how to add a login with facebook but no result, is this possible?

Comment: Of course it should be _possible_ - but it might mean that you have to implement most of it yourself.

Comment: @CBroe so , I should handle API calling when login and save user's access token and data in my DB right ? is there' any workaround because I've tried this and it didn't work

Comment: That would be the basic process, yes. Essentially you would follow the flow as outlined in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow That would be as far as getting the access token. “Telling” your system that a user is authenticated might need additional steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed  this link 
, when getting the data from the API call Fb.api('me'), make an ajax call to fetch the response and save it in DB and check each login if users exist or not also saving access token instead of a password.